# How to manage realtime push notifications for large number of users?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, push-notification, cron, cpu-usage

I have a cron service running in the background every minute. The cron service is responsible to send realtime notifications to users based on a complex logic. It is mandatory for the cron to complete processing and deliver push notifications to all the users within the given minute. I use a third party push notification service to manage the delivery of the push notifications.

At any given minute, I have 50,000 users (increasing with time) who might be possible candidates to receive these notifications. I iterate through 50,000 users in a `for loop` in batches of 1000 to perform my application logic. The application logic involves 20+ simple database queries per user.

1. Is this a recommended architecture?
2. When the cron executes,  the CPU utilisation shoots upto 100% for a span 3-4 seconds, 4-5 times a minute. The repeated 100% utilisation is because I have added delays between subsequent heavy computations to even the utilisation over a minute. Should  I be concerned about this?